# Pyinstaller Codec Error on Executable When Using No Console And No Debug Option

Tags: python, tkinter, video, pyinstaller, python-imageio

I'm making this program that uses imageio and imageio-ffmpeg, I want to turn it into an executable, so I entered the virtualenv environment I'm using for the project, generated the .spec with `pyi-makespec`, and after trying for a long time, I got it working by adding this into the `binaries` section of the .spec file:

```
binaries=[("C:\\Users\\me\\video_env\\Lib\\site-packages\\imageio_ffmpeg", "imageio_ffmpeg"), ("C:\\Users\\me\\video_env\\Lib\\site-packages\\imageio", "imageio")],
```

Then I changed `console` and `debug` to `True`, and I generated the executable. And it works. Now that everything was working, I changed `console` and `debug` to `False` again, generated the executable, and this time it no longer works. The program opens correctly, but when it reaches the place that uses imageio, it crashes and I get this error window from pyinstaller:

[image: Error Message]

Just to be sure, I turned on `console` and `debug` again, and sure enough, it works again:
[image: It's Working]

It also works if I have `debug=False` and `console=True`, but it doesn't work with `debug=True` and `console=False`. Am I making a mistake with the binares? I have no idea how to fix this, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working, it's a bug in pyinstaller. It worked when I used the development version of pyinstaller. I ran `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip` in cmd, and ran the pyinstaller command again, and it worked.